# Proving that $\frac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n n z^n}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n}$ is strictly increasing.

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Im considering the quotient from the title:
$$g(z)=\frac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\cdot a_n z^n}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n}$$
with $a_n>0$  $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ and for all $z\in(0,1)$. And assuming that both sums suffice the requirements necessary in order to differentiate, etc. What I want to prove is that $g'(z)>0$ and $g''(z)\geq 0$ (Im pretty sure about the truth of the second identity but not 100% sure).

I've been able to prove the first identity deriving with respect to z and then using the Cauchy formula for the coefficient of the product of two infinite series. (If requested I can post it but it's way too cumbersome to be useful to prove that $g''(z)\geq 0$). I also think that there must be an easier and smarter way to prove it (In fact it may be trivial but I just haven't thought of it).

I would appreciate any help and thanks in advance.

Edit: I've asked this because I think it could be a general property, but the problem this actually comes from is with this specific $a_n$ (if it can be proven for this case I'd be happy too)

$$a_n = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{k}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2} \right) \cdot \Gamma\left(1 +\frac{1}{k}\right)}\cdot \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2} + n \right) \Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{k} + n \right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{k}+ n \right)} \cdot \frac{1}{n!}$$

where $k>0$ is a positive constant. And this problems in itself comes from trying to prove that both the first and second derivative of the following quotient are positive:

$$\frac{_2F_1\left(\frac{3}{2},1+\frac{1}{k};\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{k};z \right) }{_2F_1\left(\frac{3}{2},1+\frac{1}{k};\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{k};z \right) }$$

Comment: Please don't use \displaystyle in titles.

Comment: My bad, won't happen again.

Comment: Take $a_n = \frac1{n!}$, then $g(z) = z$ and $g''(z) = 0$.

Comment: I'm going to edit it in order to make $g''$ be greater or equal to 0.

Answer (score 4):

Even when the inequality changed to $g''(z) \ge 0$, it need not be true.

For an counterexample, take $a_n = \begin{cases}\frac1{n!},& n \ne 1,\\ \frac12 & n = 1\end{cases}$. The denominator of this $g(z)$ is
$$D(z) \stackrel{def}{=} \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n = e^z - \frac{z}{2}$$
From this, we can deduce
$$g(z) = \frac{\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty n a_n z^n}{\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n} = z\frac{d}{dz}\log(D(z)) = z \frac{e^z - \frac12}{e^z - \frac{z}{2}}$$
If one throw $g(z)$ to a CAS and make a plot of $g''(z)$, one will notice $g''(z) < 0$ for $z \in [1, \sim\!3.81787380305645 ]$.

Comment: Wow thanks. Guess it wasn't as general as i thought, but still for the ratio of hypergeometricals I "know" it has to be true (at least so it seems with Mathematica). Any advice on how to prove it for that case?

Comment: @Rafa  no idea. one possible approach is look at the ODE satisfied by the numerator/denominators,  express $g''$ as lower order derivatives of them and see whether one can get something useful.